# How to call multiple mutations at the same time?

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I have an array of ids, and I created a mutation that allow me to delete an item using only 1 id. 
Is there any way to call this mutation multiple times using `Relay.Store.commitUpdate` or `this.props.relay.commitUpdate` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can wrap each Relay.Store.commitUpdate in Promise:

```js
    commitMutationPromise = (Mutation, data) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Relay.Store.commitUpdate(new Mutation(data), {
          onSuccess: (transaction) => {
            resolve(transaction);
          },
          onFailure: (transaction) => {
            reject(transaction);
          },
        });
      }
```

And commit your mutations as array of promises and catch result with Promise.all(but keep in mind its fail-fast behaviour).
It could be something like this:

```js
      handleDelete = (deleteIds) => {
        const deletePromisesArray = [];
        deleteIds.forEach(id => {
            deletePromisesArray.push(
              this.commitMutationPromise(DeleteMutation, { id })
            );
        });
        Promise.all(deletePromisesArray).then(values => {
              this.onSuccessDelete(result);
            }, error => {
              this.onFailDelete(error);
            });
      }
```